# How can I pass function arguments with a function pointer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arguments, function-pointers

This is a syntax question I assume. Using function pointers is new to me, and required for a chunk of code I am working with. I want to pass some arguments to LoadResourceList to explain how to handle the data. LoadResourceList is a callback for when the ajaxObject has finished loading.

```
var getResourceList=new ajaxObject("resources.json",LoadResourceList); // Load Resource List
getResourceList.update();
```

Comment: There's no pointers in Javascript, only references. When you mention a function by name, it's the same as you mention it 'by reference'; this way you pass functions as parameters, assign them to variables, etc. You handle any other objects the same way. You already know how to handle 'function pointers', you just don't realize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arguments for `LoadResourceList` into `ajaxObject` aswell:

```
function ajaxObject(json, callback) {
    // code
    if( typeof callback === 'function' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        callback.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```